# Unit Testing with Viper - Swift & iOS

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

Unit testing with Viper - Swift

Hello,

I have an Login module(LoginViewController,LoginPresenter,LoginInteractor,LoginRouter)
that I wrote with Viper.
I want to write a unit test for this module but I'm not sure exactly where to start.
Can I get suggestions from people who write unit tests with Viper?
Thank you,

Comment: You need to set viper modules (presenter,interactor,router,view) in Unit test's setUp function like setting a new viewcontroller for viper module

Comment: Hi Ömer, thanks for your reply. For now I'm trying to detect the Login Presenter and Login Interactor classes. I created two test classes for these. I aim to write cases for them if I can understand their logic.

Comment: The whole _point_ of viper is that it is _eminently_ testable. Simply mock all members of the module except the one you are testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by learning about dependency injection and how it can be useful for testing your module layers. Then you can explore the concept of test doubles. These are the main concepts that helped me a lot in the beginning.

Here are some useful links:

[Dependency Injection](https://cocoacasts.com/dependency-injection-in-swift)

[Test doubles](https://swiftsenpai.com/testing/test-doubles-in-swift/)

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for your reply. I'll look at the links you forwarded, if you have a different opinion, please feel free to repost. :)

Answer (score 0):

In [PROJECTNAME]Tests folder, create Unit Test Case Class file and follow the particular architecture (not necessary). Write test cases in that file and XCode supports is enough for you to easily understand whole process.

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for your reply. But I need more detailed suggestions. For example, you should test the presenter and interactor classes. Example code/project this figure etc.

Comment: You need to make presenterTesting XCTest File and write test cases for that class, In that UnitTests Folder